# Return the Boss in the hierarchy -- Tried to apply Depth First Search

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

XYZ is a company which has CEO Bill and a hierarchy of employees. Employees can have a list of other employees reporting to them, which can themselves have reports, and so on. An employee with at least one report is called a manager.
Please implement the closestCommonManager method to find the closest manager (i.e. farthest from the CEO) to two employees. You may assume that all employees eventually report up to the CEO.

Sample Data: 
CEO Bill has 3 employees reporting to him: {Dom, Samir, Michael}

Dom has three reports { Peter, Bob, Porter}

Samir has no reports {} Michael has no reports {}

Peter has 2 reports {Milton, Nina} Bob has no reports {}

Porter has no reports {} Milton has no reports {}

Nina has no reports {}

Sample calls: 
closestCommonManager(Milton, Nina) = Peter

closestCommonManager(Nina, Porter) = Dom

closestCommonManager(Nina, Samir) = Bill

closestCommonManager(Peter, Nina) = Peter

Now, to solve this problem i have approached like this - but i haven't got the solution. 
I have tried to use simple DFS algorithm, but couldn't complete the solution.

```
    public static Employee closestCommonManager(Employee ceo, Employee firstEmployee, Employee secondEmployee)
    {
        var visited = new HashSet<Employee>();
        bool firstFound = false, secondFound = false;

        Stack<Employee> stack = new Stack<Employee>(); // DFS
        stack.Push(ceo);

        while (stack.Count != 0)
        {
            Employee current = stack.Pop();
            IList<Employee> employeeList = current.getReports();

            if (firstEmployee.getId() == current.getId())
            {
                firstFound = true;
            }
            else if (secondEmployee.getId() == current.getId())
            {
                secondFound = true;
            }

            if (firstFound && secondFound)
                return current;
            // Should i return previous one? how do i keep track of the
            // node which i found first in hierarchy ???


            Console.WriteLine(current.getName());

            foreach (var employee in employeeList)
            {
                if (visited.Add(employee))
                {
                    stack.Push(employee);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is DFS a requirement? You could just work the other way: start from the first employee and walk up the management chain. Put each person in a set. Then walk up from the second person, checking to see at each step if that person is in the set. The first person you find in the set is the closest common manager.

Comment: There is no link from Child -> Parent, we have only Parent->Child link. So in that case we will have to traverse through the graph and create a HashMap/Dictionary kinda structure where Key=Child, Value=Parent - and go through the structure till you reach to Top that is CEO. And after that we will require to adopt the approach you suggested for the HashSet or something... But Can we do better? Can we simply use DFS to resolve this?

Comment: Also - I attempted to use DFS - i thought i will be able to crack it but i got lost midway -- Anyone can put some light on it please? What else do i need to do to complete my code sample above?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a request for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor. Clever algorithms for this usually do some pre-processing on the tree. One simple way is to mark each element in the tree with its distance from the root. Then to find the closest common ancestor of two nodes first move a pointer up from the lower one so they are both at the same depth, and then move both pointers up together until the pointers touch. If you don't get to do pre-processing, you could move up from both nodes at once, adding all the nodes you see to a set, and checking when you add a node to the set of nodes encountered that is already there. In either case, the first time you encounter a node from both sides, that node is the lowest common ancestor.

Comment: I don't see limitation 'each employee reports only to one manager', so it might be not a tree and there can be several paths from leaf to root.

Comment: In that case I would work up from both employees one step at a time on each side, but instead of maintaining a pointer, I would be maintaining a set of pointers. You might need to carry on for a while after the first match, though, because if an employee can report to two managers then different chains from each employee upwards might have different lengths, and the first match you find might not be the match furthest from the CEO. I guess this is really two breadth first searches upwards at once.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with DFS

Separate tasks. 
Create DFS function to find PATH from root to worker. (list or stack)
Call it for both workers then compare paths from root to worker. 
Last match is your goal

Answer (score 0):

In this solution I've added two fields to `Employee`:

```
//all managers of this Employee
public List<Employee> Bosses = new List<Employee>();
//how many managers between employee and Ceo
public int DistanceFromCeo = 0;
```

This code finds all bosses of first and second employee and stores them in their `Bosses` field

```
var stack = new Stack<Employee>(); // DFS
stack.Push(ceo);

while (stack.Count != 0)
{
    var current = stack.Pop();
    IList<Employee> employeeList = current.getReports();

    foreach (var employee in employeeList)
    {
        employee.Bosses.AddRange(current.Bosses);
        employee.Bosses.Add(current);
        employee.DistanceFromCeo = current.DistanceFromCeo + 1;
        if (firstEmployee.getId() == employee.getId())
        {
            firstEmployee.Bosses.AddRange(employee.Bosses);
        }
        if (secondEmployee.getId() == employee.getId())
        {
            secondEmployee.Bosses.AddRange(employee.Bosses);
        }

        stack.Push(employee);
    }
}
```

now it is easy to get answer - join bosses and find most distant:

```
var commonBosses = (from f in firstEmployee.Bosses
    join s in firstEmployee.Bosses on f.getId() equals s.getId()
    select f).ToList();
var maxLenght = commonBosses.Max(b => b.DistanceFromCeo);

return commonBosses.FirstOrDefault(b => b.DistanceFromCeo == maxLenght);
```

It will work only if there is no cycles in hierarchy. But I guess if there is cycles then it is unclear who is the farthest, if you run through the cycle dinstance will grow infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static Employee ret;
    public static bool first = false;
    public static bool second = false;
    public static Employee closestCommonManager(Employee ceo, Employee firstEmployee, Employee secondEmployee)
    {
        // Implement me                                                
        if (ceo == null || firstEmployee == null || secondEmployee == null)
            return null;
        if (ceo.getId() == firstEmployee.getId())
            first = true;
        if (ceo.getId() == secondEmployee.getId())
            second = true;
        if (first && second)
            return ceo;
        else
        {
            foreach (Employee e in ceo.getReports())
            {
                if (ret == null)
                {
                    var r = closestCommonManager(e, firstEmployee, secondEmployee);
                    if (r != null && ret == null)
                        ret = ceo;
                }
                else
                    return ret;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my solution but from some reason it wasn't accepted:

```
public static Employee closestCommonManager(Employee ceo, Employee firstEmployee, Employee secondEmployee)
{

    // Implement me
    var Manager = ceo.getReports();
    Employee tempEmployee = ceo;
    foreach (var HisReporter in Manager)
    {
        if (HisReporter.Equals(firstEmployee) || HisReporter.Equals(secondEmployee))
        {
            //if one of the employees are reporting to him return manager
            tempEmployee = ceo;
        }
        else if(HisReporter.getReports().Count > 0)
        {
            //if non of the employees reporting to him check if his reporters having these employees
            tempEmployee = closestCommonManager(HisReporter, firstEmployee, secondEmployee);
        }
    }
    return tempEmployee;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementaion with DFS as suggested by Krzysztof Bardzinski

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Employee> employeeMap = new Dictionary<int, Employee>();
        Employee ceo = null, firstEmployee = null, secondEmployee = null;
        /*//Sample input
         List<string> input = new List<string>();
         input.Add("employee 1 A");
         input.Add("employee 2 B");
         input.Add("employee 3 C");
         input.Add("employee 4 D");
         input.Add("employee 5 E");
         input.Add("employee 6 F");
         input.Add("employee 7 G");
         input.Add("employee 8 H");
         input.Add("employee 9 I");
         input.Add("employee 10 J");
         input.Add("employee 11 K");
         input.Add("employee 12 L");
         input.Add("employee 13 M");

         input.Add("report 1 2");
         input.Add("report 1 3");

         input.Add("report 2 4");
         input.Add("report 2 5");
         input.Add("report 2 6");

         input.Add("report 5 7");
         input.Add("report 5 8");

         input.Add("report 6 9");
         input.Add("report 6 10");

         input.Add("report 3 11");
         input.Add("report 3 12");
         input.Add("report 3 13");

         input.Add("params 1 9 13");*/

        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] tokens = line.Split();
            string type = tokens[0];

            if (type.Equals("employee"))
            {
                int id = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
                String name = tokens[2];
                employeeMap.Add(id, new Employee(id, name));
            }
            else if (type.Equals("report"))
            {
                Employee manager = employeeMap[int.Parse(tokens[1])];
                Employee report = employeeMap[int.Parse(tokens[2])];
                manager.addReport(report);
            }
            else if (type.Equals("params"))
            {
                ceo = employeeMap[int.Parse(tokens[1])];
                firstEmployee = employeeMap[int.Parse(tokens[2])];
                secondEmployee = employeeMap[int.Parse(tokens[3])];
            }
            else
            {
                // ignore comments and whitespace
            }
        }

        Employee result = closestCommonManager(ceo, firstEmployee, secondEmployee);
    } 
public static Employee closestCommonManager(Employee ceo, Employee firstEmployee, Employee secondEmployee)
    {
        Stack<Employee> firstManagers = new Stack<Employee>();
        Stack<Employee> secondManagers = new Stack<Employee>();
        if (ceo.getReports().Count > 0)
        {
            searchManager(ceo, firstEmployee, firstManagers);
            searchManager(ceo, secondEmployee, secondManagers);
            if (firstManagers.Contains(secondEmployee))
            {
                return secondEmployee; //closest manager as this is managing the first one
            }
            if (secondManagers.Contains(firstEmployee))
            {
                return firstEmployee; //closest manager as this is managing the second one
            }

            //check for closest match

            //make them equal in length.
            while (firstManagers.Count > secondManagers.Count)
            {
                firstManagers.Pop();
            }

            while (secondManagers.Count > firstManagers.Count)
            {
                secondManagers.Pop();
            }
            int checkCount = firstManagers.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < checkCount; i++)
            {
                if (firstManagers.Peek().getId() == secondManagers.Peek().getId())
                {
                    return firstManagers.Pop();
                }
                else
                {
                    firstManagers.Pop();
                    secondManagers.Pop();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static bool searchManager(Employee manager, Employee emp, Stack<Employee> graph)
    {
        bool res = false;
        graph.Push(manager);
        foreach (Employee e in manager.getReports())
        {
            if (e.getId() == emp.getId())
            {
                res = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.getReports().Count > 0)
                {
                    if (searchManager(e, emp, graph))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        graph.Pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

 public sealed class Employee
{

    private readonly int id;
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly List<Employee> reports;

    public Employee(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.reports = new List<Employee>();
    }

    /// <returns> 
    /// an integer ID for this employee, guaranteed to be unique.
    /// </returns> 
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    /// <returns> 
    /// a String name for this employee, NOT guaranteed to be unique.
    /// </returns> 
    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /// <returns> 
    /// a List of employees which report to this employee.  This list may be empty, but will
    /// never be null.
    /// </returns> 
    public IList<Employee> getReports()
    {
        return reports;
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Adds the provided employee as a report of this employee. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void addReport(Employee employee)
    {
        reports.Add(employee);
    }
}
```